# pandas groupby: an overall/total row?

Tags: pandas

I have the following:

```
maths = {'floatval': 'mean'}
out = df.groupby(['pid', 'year', 'month']).agg(maths)
```

Which gives me a grouped mean of `floatval` per year and month, which is great, but I want an all/overall row, which has the `mean` val of `floatval` across a row just grouped by `pid`. Should I make a second data frame and combine, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: yes, you should have another group by `df.groupby(['pid']).agg(maths)` . This would give you the mean value of the rows grouped by the pid.

Comment: How would you most efficiently merge that second group by with the original?

Comment: do you just want the mean to be separate column along with other columns? is that what you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding total row to pandas DataFrame groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326903/adding-total-row-to-pandas-dataframe-groupby)