# Adding total row to pandas DataFrame groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I am aware of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712739/pandas-groupby-an-overall-total-row) but I didn't manage to solve my problem.

I have this below DataFrame from `pandas.DataFrame.groupby().sum()`:

```
                                                          Value
Level      Company         Item
    1            X            a                             100
                              b                             200
                 Y            a                              35
                              b                             150
                              c                              35
    2            X            a                              48
                              b                             100
                              c                              50
                 Y            a                              80
```

and would like to add total rows for each level of index that I have to get:

```
                                                          Value
Level      Company         Item
    1            X            a                             100
                              b                             200
                          Total                             300
                 Y            a                              35
                              b                             150
                              c                              35
                          Total                             520
             Total                                          820
    2            X            a                              48
                              b                             100
                              c                              50
             Total                                          198
                 Y            a                              80
                          Total                              80
               Total                                        278
Total                                                      1098
```

As request

```
level = list(map(int, list('111112222')))
company = list('XXYYYXXXY')
item = list('ababcabca')
value = [100,200,35,150,35,48,100,50,80]
col = ['Level', 'Company', 'Item', 'Value']
df = pd.DataFrame([level,company,item,value]).T
df.columns = col
df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item']).sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try stacking it one level at a time:

```
m = df.groupby(['Level','Company','Item'])['Value'].sum().unstack(level=['Company','Item'])
m = m.assign(total=m.sum(1))
m = m.stack(level='Company')
m = m.assign(total=m.sum(1))
m = m.stack(level='Item')
```

The output has duplicate totals though:

```
Level  Company  Item 
1      X        a        100.0
                b        200.0
                total    300.0
       Y        a         35.0
                b        150.0
                c         35.0
                total    220.0
       total             520.0
                total    520.0
2      X        a         48.0
                b        100.0
                c         50.0
                total    198.0
       Y        a         80.0
                total     80.0
       total             278.0
                total    278.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks! Could you help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59364298/adding-total-row-to-a-pandas-dataframe-with-tuples-inside ? @Yen

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
m=df.groupby(['Level','Company','Item'])['Value'].sum().unstack()
m.assign(total=m.sum(1)).stack().to_frame('Value')
```

---

```
                     Value
Level Company Item        
1     X       a      100.0
              b      200.0
              total  300.0
      Y       a       35.0
              b      150.0
              c       35.0
              total  220.0
2     X       a       48.0
              b      100.0
              c       50.0
              total  198.0
      Y       a       80.0
              total   80.0
```

Comment: nice solution, however I am not able to make it work with more than one column to sum. How could that be solved ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Basically, this is creating two new dfs from the using the sum of the two groups and concating the three data frames

```
level = list(map(int, list('111112222')))
company = list('XXYYYXXXY')
item = list('ababcabca')
value = [100,200,35,150,35,48,100,50,80]
col = ['Level', 'Company', 'Item', 'Value']
df = pd.DataFrame([level,company,item,value]).T
df.columns = col

df1 = (df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item'])['Value'].sum())
df2 = (df1.sum(level=0).to_frame().assign(Company='total').set_index('Company', append=True))
df3 = (df1.groupby(['Level','Company']).sum().to_frame().assign(Item='total').set_index('Item', append=True))

dfx = pd.concat([df1.to_frame().reset_index(),
                 df2.reset_index(),
                 df3.reset_index()],sort=False)
print(dfx)
```

Output:

```
   Level Company   Item  Value
0      1       X      a    100
1      1       X      b    200
2      1       Y      a     35
3      1       Y      b    150
4      1       Y      c     35
5      2       X      a     48
6      2       X      b    100
7      2       X      c     50
8      2       Y      a     80
0      1   total    NaN    520
1      2   total    NaN    278
0      1       X  total    300
1      1       Y  total    220
2      2       X  total    198
3      2       Y  total     80
```

This is not sorted though as you expect. 
If I concat the 3 dfs without resetting the index I'm getting the expected sort order, but the index is a multi-index column

```
dfx = pd.concat([df1.to_frame(), df2, df3]).sort_index()
```

Output

```
               Value
(1, X, a)        100
(1, X, b)        200
(1, X, total)    300
(1, Y, a)         35
(1, Y, b)        150
(1, Y, c)         35
(1, Y, total)    220
(1, total)       520
(2, X, a)         48
(2, X, b)        100
(2, X, c)         50
(2, X, total)    198
(2, Y, a)         80
(2, Y, total)     80
(2, total)       278
```

I am not sure how to convert this to columns as in your df.

Comment: Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: The last dataframe has a KeyError: ‘Level’

Comment: Do you have a column called 'Level' in your dataframe? Can you post which statement exactly you are getting the error?

Comment: I do, on the initial one. The error is on the 4th line. df1 is a Series so you can’t groupby I guess this is the issue.

Comment: Using your example,  I am able to run this statement `print(df1.groupby(['Level','Company']).sum().to_frame().assign(Company='total').set_index('Company', append=True))` without any errors.

Comment: is the `df1` on `df1.groupby(['Level','Company']).sum().to_frame().assign(Company='total').set_index('Company', append=True)` the same than the `df1` in this following line: `df1 = (df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item'])['Value'].sum())`. If yes, how could we `groupby` `df1` once more ? After the first line, `df1` becomes a `pandas.Series` and we can't `groupby` `pandas.Series`.

Comment: Yes, df1 is the result of `df1 = (df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item'])['Value'].sum())`. See [pandas.Series.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html)

Comment: Can I see your output please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204427/discussion-between-user12392864-and-davidbilla).

Comment: thanks. It doesn’t work on Jupyter but does work on Pycharm.

Comment: Super. That may be due to version differences. Are you using the same pandas version in both IDEs?