# Adding total row to a pandas DataFrame with tuples inside

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326903/adding-total-row-to-pandas-dataframe-groupby) (that has been answered). It helped me for my initial problem but now I am stuck on another one.

I have this below `pandas.DataFrame` which I try to add total rows for each sub levels.

```
Level  Company  Item
1      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
2      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
```

I would like to get this :

```
Level  Company  Item
1      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                total   (20, 40)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
                total   (30, 60)
       total            (50, 100)
                total   (50, 100)
2      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
                total   (30, 60)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
                total   (10, 20)
       total            (40, 80)
                total   (40, 80)
```

To get the dataframe :

```
level = list(map(int, list('111112222')))
company = list('XXYYYXXXY')
item = list('ababcabca')
value = [(10,20)]*9
col = ['Level', 'Company', 'Item', 'Value']
df = pd.DataFrame([level,company,item,value]).T
df.columns = col
df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item'])['Value'].sum()
```

But my result is :

```
Level  Company  Item
1      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
       total            (50, 100)
2      X        a       (10, 20)
                b       (10, 20)
                c       (10, 20)
       Y        a       (10, 20)
       total            (40, 80)
```

Using the below script:

```
def f(x):
    return tuple(sum(x) for x in zip(*filter(lambda x: type(x) == tuple, x)))
m=df.unstack(level=['Company','Item'])
m=m.assign(total=m.apply(f, axis=1))
m=m.stack(level='Company')
m=m.assign(total=m.apply(f))
m=m.stack(level='Item')
m
```

Comment: does every tuple always have 2 elements?

Comment: @AndyL. No, on the real case they have N elements so I’d rather have a general solution.

Comment: whats the purpose of having the order like this? for presentation?

Comment: in case of 1 row has tuple of 2 elements and another has 3 elements such as : `(5, 10)` and `(7, 15, 3)`, what is your expected output of this case?

Comment: @Datanovice The ability to get the total for each sub levels when we filter the data in an excel sheet for instance

Comment: @AndyL. Every tuple within the dataframe will have the same length. It is just not necessary 2.

Comment: why don't you just group it in excel then? it's much easier to create subtotals there plus it works with the filters?

Comment: Because the length of my tuples are so huge that sometimes it is impossible to process it with excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#s=df.groupby(['Level', 'Company', 'Item'])['Value'].sum()

def GetTupleSum(x):
    return tuple(sum(y) for y in zip(*x.dropna()))

df= s.unstack('Item')
df['total']=df.apply(GetTupleSum,axis=1)
( df.unstack()
    .assign(total_company=df['total'].groupby(level=0).apply(GetTupleSum) )
    .stack(['Company','Item']) )
```

**Output**

```
Level  Company  Item         
1      X        a                 (10, 20)
                b                 (10, 20)
                total             (20, 40)
       Y        a                 (10, 20)
                b                 (10, 20)
                c                 (10, 20)
                total             (30, 60)
                total_company    (50, 100)
2      X        a                 (10, 20)
                b                 (10, 20)
                c                 (10, 20)
                total             (30, 60)
       Y        a                 (10, 20)
                total             (10, 20)
                total_company     (40, 80)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. What about the total rows for the Company column ?

Comment: please check now:) If it works consider accept or upvote

Comment: This works for the example you showed, could you give more details?